# How to turn off logging statements without removing them from the code

Tags: python, logging, xdebug

If there are logging statements spread throughout a codebase, how do I set up the logger so I don't have to comment out each call to the logger when deploying the code into production?

Here's my current code:

```
import logging


logging.basicConfig(filename='./example.log', level=logging.DEBUG, 
                    format='%(asctime)s %(name)-12s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s',
                    datefmt='%m-%d %H:%M')

logging.debug('debug failed')
logging.info('info failed')
logging.warning('A warning')
```

Comment: Isn't this basic logging 101?

Comment: @delman: if its 101 then please write a best practice answer

Comment: I'm not qualified for that, I'm just rather certain that the obvious way of doing it, setting filtering to reject all messages, is described in any decent logging tutorial.

Comment: Are you trying to silence all levels? Or just debug?

Comment: @Jdi Silence all. So, run as if statements were passed over.

Comment: Looks like you have accepted this answer. Perhaps you should mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using the `basicConfig`, you can set up the logger more explicitly with the handlers you want, based on any criteria.

```
import logging

log = logging.getLogger("FOO")
log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# needs a handler
log.info('info')
#No handlers could be found for logger "FOO"

ch = logging.StreamHandler()
log.addHandler(ch)
log.info('info')
# info

log.removeHandler(ch)

noop = logging.NullHandler()
log.addHandler(noop)
# nothing happens here
log.info('info')
```

You can have a conditional statement that either adds the handler you want if you are running in debug mode, or you can add a `NullHandler` that just absorbs the log messages. You can also configure the levels individually of each handler, so that you would always see warnings and above. Each handler can have its own level, in addition to the main logger.

You can [refer to the tutorials](http://docs.python.org/howto/logging.html#logging-basic-tutorial) on how to get more specific with levels, handlers, and formatting.

Comment: I see your point, The real question: Can set filter to warning, and have warning go into a blackhole. When needed dump to file maybe playing with NullHandler.

Comment: Playing with basicConfig and setting level to '99', seemed to work. file created, no print to console or file.

Comment: You can add different handlers based on flags in the script. If you run it with a debug flag you could have it add a file handler. Otherwise you add a null handler. And you can add multiple handlers. Maybe a StreamHandler set to warning always prints warnings or greater, and then the optional file handler is set to debug to catch all your debug levels. Setting the level to 99 just makes it so high that no log levels will match it. Its not really a common way.

Answer (score 3):

There are levels of logging.  Based on the severity of the logging level, it will print it.

```
Level   Numeric value
CRITICAL    50
ERROR   40
WARNING     30
INFO    20
DEBUG   10
NOTSET  0
```

Based on the logging level it will print the statements.

the level you have specified here is level=logging.DEBUG.  So all but notset logging levels should print out.  If you would want to print out only critical levels, please change the level=logging.CRITICAL

http://docs.python.org/release/2.5/lib/module-logging.html has more information

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of really simple answers here. The first is to simply comment out the `basicConfig(...)` statement. That will have the effect not setting up any of the loggers, handlers or formatters which means your debug(), info(), etc calls will be effectively no-ops.

Another simple answer is to set the logging level in the `basicConfig()` call to something higher than `DEBUG`. `CRITICAL + 1` would make sure that you never see a log message.

However you mentioned something about moving this code into production, so what you probably want to do is provide `-q` and `-v` command line options (assuming this is a CLI tool). My usual approach is to start at `WARNING` level, and for each `-q` move towards quieter logging by increasing the filter level. Conversely, for each `-v`, move towards more verbose logging. Here is a snippet of code that does exactly that.

```
from argparse import ArgumentParser
from logging import basicConfig, CRITICAL, ERROR, WARNING, INFO, DEBUG

parser = ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-v", "--verbose", action="count")
parser.add_argument("-q", "--quiet", action="count")

arguments = parser.parse_args()

raw_log_level = 2 + (arguments.verbose or 0) - (arguments.quiet or 0)
if raw_log_level <= 0: 
    log_level = CRITICAL
elif raw_log_level == 1:
    log_level = ERROR
elif raw_log_level == 2:     # default
    log_level = WARNING
elif raw_log_level == 3: 
    log_level = INFO
else:         
    log_level = DEBUG

basicConfig(level=log_level)
```